# Table extending past container

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to PHP/HTML/CSS, and trying to develop a visitor messaging system on someone's profile. The code works fine, gets entered into the database etc. The issue I'm having is that the vmdisplay table (the table that pulls up the visitor messages) completely ignoring the limits of the container it's in, and is coming off of the page.

The display for the visitor messages is under another table called vminput. Here's the code:

```
    <form action="profile.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" name="post_vm">
        <table class="vminput">
            <tr>
                <td><br> <textarea name="vm_message" class="vm" /></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <div align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Post visitor message" name="post_vm"></td></div>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

and here's the code for the vmdisplay

```
         <table class="vmdisplay">
                <tr>
                    <td><h2><?php echo $sender; ?> - <?php echo $date; ?></small></td>
                    <td width=100px align="right"><a href=""> Delete message</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="vm_disp"><?php echo $message; ?> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

and here's the CSS for both:

```
.vminput{
   width:500px;
   float:right;
   height:200px;
   display:block; 
 }
.vmdisplay{
max-width:500px;
float:right;
clear:right;
}
```

Here's an example of what's happeing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u0sb.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give `overflow-y:scroll;` a try.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Sorry, my bad. It's been updated. overflow-y:scroll; on the .vmdisplay{ isn't doing anything.

Comment: Which way is the content of the table veering off the page?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Downwards. Usually when I would reach the bottom of the page, the container would extend. http://i.imgur.com/b8HHiiz.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nag2d8w7/) created based on your problem. In this the php scripts are removed as i don't have the database connectivity. But the code structure remains same just replace the text messages with your php. If the content is very large then a scroll bar comes.

## HERE is your display html page:

```
    <table class="vmdisplay" border="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td><h2>Date</small></td>
                                <td><a href=""> Delete message</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><div class="msg">Hello this is a big message guessing your messsage to be too big . Here is again some more message.
                                    Hello this is a big message guessing your messsage to be too big . Here is again some more message.</div></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

## CSS [add this after your remaining css]

```
            .vmdisplay{
            width:400px;
            float:right;
            height:200px;
            }
            .vmdisplay .msg{
                width:100%;
                height:60%;
                word-wrap:word-break;
                overflow-y:scroll;
            }
```

> In your above css you forgot to define the vmdisplay class, instead you defined vminput two times. let me know if any further help you need.. Cheers , All The Best.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I believe I may have explained my issue incorrectly. I've updated the original post with the link to the image of what's happening. - the issue isn't within the length of the VM, but that they are ignoring the container it seems.

Comment: @buggeroff according to the image that you added, still the problem remains the same. Add some height and overflow proper it will work for sure..        `.txtclass{width:200px; height:200px;overflow:scroll;}`  here i used .txtclass just for example you can use as per yours. and also change the width and height as per your requirement. Cheers.....